# How can I customize column-mapping when save RDD to Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using Java to write Spark application.
If I have a customized tuple, let's say class "Person".

```
Class Person { 
  public String name1; 
  public String name2; 
  public String name3; 
}
```

And I have a

```
JavaRDD<Person> rdd;
```

Now I want to save it to Cassandra.

Assume that I have a table called "people" with three columns "name1", "name2" and "name3", "name4", ..., "name10" in Cassandra.
According to the tutorial, the default column-mapping is using this code:

```
javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("test", "person", mapToRow(Person.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

This will use the default column-mapping like:

```
Person.name1  --> "name1"    
Person.name2  --> "name2"     
Person.name3  --> "name3"
```

But I want to customize the column mapping, the new mapping looks like this:

```
Person.name1  --> "name3"       
Person.name2  --> "name2"  
Person.name3  --> "name1"
```

or even that I want to discard Person.name2

```
Person.name1  --> "name3"
Person.name3  --> "name1"
```

Anyway, I wonder if there is way to override or replace the default RowWriter?
What should I do to modify the column-mapping ?
I cannot find any good material about customized column-mapping in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the signature of saveTOCassandra

```
def saveToCassandra(keyspaceName: String, 
                    tableName: String, columns: 
                    ColumnSelector = AllColumns, 
                     writeConf: WriteConf = WriteConf.fromSparkConf(sparkContext.getConf))
```

Explanation:

> @param table table definition used to create a new table
>
> @param columns Selects the columns to save data to.
> Uses only the unique column names, and you must select at least all primary key columns. All other fields are discarded.Non-selected property/column names are left unchanged.

If I understood your need correctly, you can use the parameter "column" to achieve your result.

Comment: kindly ccept the answer

Comment: My cassandra table columns in lower case like below
CREATE TABLE model_family_by_id(
model_family_id int PRIMARY KEY,
model_family text,
create_date   date,
last_update_date date,
model_family_name text
);

Comment: my dataframe schema is like this
 root
           |-- MODEL_FAMILY_ID: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
           |-- MODEL_FAMILY: string (nullable = true)
           |-- CREATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
           |-- LAST_UPDATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
           |-- MODEL_FAMILY_NAME: string (nullable = true)

Comment: So while insert into tabException in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Columns not found in table sample_cbd.model_family_by_id: MODEL_FAMILY_ID, MODEL_FAMILY, CREATE_DATE, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, MODEL_FAMILY_NAME
 at com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns.selectFrom(ColumnSelector.scala:44)
le i am getting error

Comment: how should i handle this?